# Python: passing local variable reference as string

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I use an interactive interpreter for data analysis, so I tend to just define functions and call them when I need them. In this case, I would like to call some function:

```
def function(var):
     do stuff
     ax.plot(x, y) 
     blah
     ax.set_title('var')
```

where var in the function call is ndarray and var in set_title is the reference of the ndarray.

I'm currently implementing this with

```
 def function(var, varstring):
     do stuff
     ax.plot(x, y) 
     blah
     ax.set_title(varstring)
```

where var is foo and varstring is just 'foo' - an example call:

```
 module.function(foo, 'foo')
```

now, my function takes many more variables and it's unwieldy to duplicate everything over and over again, but I can't figure out how to just get var as 'var' .. any attempt to do so provides me with a string of the ndarray values.

Comment: Use `str.format()`. `module.function(foo, '{}'.format(foo))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in the interpreter, the variables are likely in the global scope. Thus, you can access them using `var = globals()[varstring]` and then pass in the string name into each function.

Note that an object (`var`) has no knowledge of its names (`varstring`) which is why the global name needs to be passed to the function rather than the object itself.

Comment: I'd recommend a lookup in a user defined dictionary rather than `globals()`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to define your function in this way:

```
def function(varstring):
    var = globals()[varstring]
    # do stuff with `var` variable
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title(varstring)
```

and then call `module.function('foo')`